# How should I modify the PHP and Javascript files so that the checkbox is mandatory?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation

I want a checkbox of my form to be mandatory, but I do not know how to modify the PHP file on the server side and the JS file.

I have read some questions and answers about this, but I can not find a way to implement what I saw in my form, since my knowledge of PHP and Javascript is scarce.

I have added a simple REQUIRED, but as I have read, that is not enough for my purpose.

I show them my HTML, PHP and JS files to see if they give me ideas of what 
I should add or modify to have this in the right way.

These are the arcivos that the form has, if I must add any more arcivo, do not hesitate to tell me what else I should show you.

Thank you

```js
//  -************** FILE PHP ************  //

<?php

/***************** Configuration *****************/

$contact_email_to = "cuentaclientdiana@gmail.com";
$contact_subject_prefix = "Mensaje de formulario de contacto: ";
$contact_error_name = "¡El nombre es demasiado corto o vacío!";
$contact_error_email = "Por favor, introduzca un email valido";
$contact_error_subject = "El tema es demasiado corto o vacío!";
$contact_error_message = "Mensaje demasiado corto! Por favor, introduzca algo.";

/********** Do not edit from the below line ***********/

if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
  die('Sorry Request must be Ajax POST');
}

if(isset($_POST)) {

  $name = filter_var($_POST["name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $email = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
  $subject = filter_var($_POST["subject"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $message = filter_var($_POST["message"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

  if(strlen($name)<4){
    die($contact_error_name);
  }

  if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    die($contact_error_email);
  }

  if(strlen($message)<3){
    die($contact_error_subject);
  }

  if(strlen($message)<3){
    die($contact_error_message);
  }

  if(!isset($contact_email_from)) {
    $contact_email_from = "contactform@" . @preg_replace('/^www\./','', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
  }

  $sendemail = mail($contact_email_to, $contact_subject_prefix . $subject, $message,
    "From:  $name <$contact_email_from>" . PHP_EOL .
    "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL .
    "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion()
  );

  if( $sendemail ) {
    echo 'OK';
  } else {
    echo 'No se pudo enviar el correo! Por favor, compruebe su configuración de correo PHP.';
  }
}
?>


// ***********  FILE   JAVASCRIPT ********* //


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
"use strict";

    //Contact
    $('form.contactForm').submit(function(){

        var f = $(this).find('.form-group'), 
        ferror = false, 
        emailExp = /^[^\s()<>@,;:\/]+@\w[\w\.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$/i;

        f.children('input').each(function(){ // run all inputs

            var i = $(this); // current input
            var rule = i.attr('data-rule');

            if( rule !== undefined ){
            var ierror=false; // error flag for current input
            var pos = rule.indexOf( ':', 0 );
            if( pos >= 0 ){
                var exp = rule.substr( pos+1, rule.length );
                rule = rule.substr(0, pos);
            }else{
                rule = rule.substr( pos+1, rule.length );
            }
            
            switch( rule ){
                case 'required':
                if( i.val()==='' ){ ferror=ierror=true; }
                break;
                
                case 'minlen':
                if( i.val().length<parseInt(exp) ){ ferror=ierror=true; }
                break;

                case 'email':
                if( !emailExp.test(i.val()) ){ ferror=ierror=true; }
                break;

                case 'checked':
                if( !i.attr('checked') ){ ferror=ierror=true; }
                break;
                
                case 'regexp':
                exp = new RegExp(exp);
                if( !exp.test(i.val()) ){ ferror=ierror=true; }
                break;
            }
                i.next('.validation').html( ( ierror ? (i.attr('data-msg') !== undefined ? i.attr('data-msg') : 'wrong Input') : '' ) ).show('blind');
            }
        });
        f.children('textarea').each(function(){ // run all inputs

            var i = $(this); // current input
            var rule = i.attr('data-rule');

            if( rule !== undefined ){
            var ierror=false; // error flag for current input
            var pos = rule.indexOf( ':', 0 );
            if( pos >= 0 ){
                var exp = rule.substr( pos+1, rule.length );
                rule = rule.substr(0, pos);
            }else{
                rule = rule.substr( pos+1, rule.length );
            }
            
            switch( rule ){
                case 'required':
                if( i.val()==='' ){ ferror=ierror=true; }
                break;
                
                case 'minlen':
                if( i.val().length<parseInt(exp) ){ ferror=ierror=true; }
                break;
            }
                i.next('.validation').html( ( ierror ? (i.attr('data-msg') != undefined ? i.attr('data-msg') : 'wrong Input') : '' ) ).show('blind');
            }
        });
        if( ferror ) return false; 
        else var str = $(this).serialize();  
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "contactform/contactform.php",
                data: str,
                success: function(msg){
                   // alert(msg);
                    if(msg == 'OK') {
                        $("#sendmessage").addClass("show");   
                        $("#errormessage").removeClass("show"); 
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#sendmessage").removeClass("show");
                        $("#errormessage").addClass("show");
                        $('#errormessage').html(msg);
                    }
                    
                }
            });
        return false;
    });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<section id="contact-page">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="center">
        <h2>Deje su mensaje</h2>
        <p class="lead">Deje su mensaje con sus ideas y veremos que es lo mejor para usted y su negocio.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row contact-wrap">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
          <div id="sendmessage">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>
          <div id="errormessage"></div>
          <form action="" method="post" role="form" class="contactForm">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name"  placeholder="Nombre" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Por favor ingrese al menos 4 caracteres" />
              <div class="validation"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email"   placeholder="Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Por favor introduzca una dirección de correo electrónico válida" />
              <div class="validation"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject"  placeholder="Tema" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Por favor ingrese al menos 8 caracteres del tema" />
              <div class="validation"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" data-rule="required" data-msg="Por favor escribe algo para nosotros" placeholder="Mensaje"></textarea>
              <div class="validation"></div>
            </div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="acceptPolicies" required="required" value="acceptPolicies" /> He leído y acepto su <a href="privacidad.html" target="_blank">Política de Privacidad</a>
            <div class="text-center"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Enviar</button></div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/.row-->
    </div>
    <!--/.container-->
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A checkbox input will simply not send anything to the form's endpoint unless it's checked.

You can therefore simply add the following code on backend side:

```
if (!isset($_POST['acceptPolicies'])) {
  // Checkbox wasn't checked, handle appropriately (error message, log, redirection, etc.)
}
```

Also, a general advice, you should avoid using `die` as much (unless right after a redirection header or such specific occurrences). If the form has input errors, rather redirect to the form after storing an error key into the session, then display the corresponding error message on the form.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution @Jeto , but I have a question. Where should I put exactly the code snippet that shows me? I do not understand PHP and I do not want to spoil the form. If you tell me where I should put it, or why I should replace your code, I would appreciate it

Comment: You could add it before the `if(strlen($name)<4){` block, for instance. You can also replace that `// comment` I put with `die('You should accept policies');` or something if you want to keep it the same way it was done for other error cases (though as I mentioned, it's not ideal). To be honest though you should probably ask whoever made that PHP script, changing code that you don't understand is not the greatest idea.

Comment: Thanks @Jeto , I just want the box checked. I have tried to add your example and it gives me syntax error :   ` if (!isset($_POST['acceptPolicies'])) {
    die($contact_error_acceptPolicies)
  }`

Comment: You're missing a `;` before the closing `}`.